# integrate whatsApp and Telegram in strapi backend

Tags: backend, telegram, whatsapp, strapi

I Cannot find any plugins for integrating **WhatsApp and Telegram** in **Strapi v3.5.0** as i am using MongoDB as a database,

i wanted to send messages to the user from backend it would be better if there are plugins or packages to install it.

Answer (score 1):

I've done some research and seems like they don't really have a specific plugin to do it.

But you can use their Forum [HERE](https://forum.strapi.io/) to see if there's a custom solution from the community.

And if you don't find anything you can create your own.